# Regex Table Path BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I have some of view definitions and this is one of the example of the view. Let's say the name of the view is in `my_project.my_dataset.my_view`:

```
WITH 
  table_data AS (
  SELECT * FROM `all-time-project.dataset_1.table_1`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `all-time-project.dataset_2.table_2`)


 SELECT * FROM table_data
```

When I got view definition from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS, then I want to generate like this
[image]

Is there any possible way to do this? I'm very new to regex, I'm so glad if you want to help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an approach using *regular expressions*, but hope it helps.

###### ■ INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` has the following [schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema):

| Column name | Data type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| referenced_tables | RECORD | **Array of tables referenced by the job**. Only populated for query jobs. |

**example**

[image]

In order to get *referenced_tables* information, you should run a job to query ***the view*** first. After that, you can search it in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` view with some conditions like your *user_email* or so to extract *referenced_tables*.

One other useful option to seach your job easily is to leave [`@@query_label`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adding-labels#adding-label-to-session) in your *JOBS* metadata. The query with *query_label* looks like:

```sql
SET @@query_label='lineage:your_view_name_or_something';

SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_view` LIMIT 0;
```

And then, you can search the *JOB* metadata from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` view and be able to use lineage information that BigQuery engine provides.

```sql
SELECT referenced_tables FROM `your-project.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` 
  WHERE 'lineage' IN UNNEST(labels.key);
```

This query will return the result like above image.

###### ■ INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW

For your expected output, you can join the above result with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW` view.

[image]